# Confused about an ARM instruction

Tags: arm

I can't figure out what this ARM instruction does:

```
strd.w          r0, r1, [r2]
```

I know that it is a store instruction which stores something at `*r2` but I'm not entirely sure what. Why are there two source registers (`r0` and `r1`) and what does the `d.w` suffix mean?

Comment: Google search found this: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mb5d_xeINZEC&pg=PA75&lpg=PA75&dq=%22strd.w%22&source=bl&ots=kNhBZGIQc8&sig=lL-i1pLOmH2W83r1MSAtWbrIUeA&hl=en&ei=BfPLTrrFGYig8QOm8_wD&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=4&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22strd.w%22&f=false

Comment: And here's the reference : http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/CIHGCADB.html

Comment: `.w` means wide instruction in Thumb mode. This instruction 32-bit, while usual size of Thumb instruction is 16-bit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This function stores the 64-bit contents of two 32-bit registers into memory. The 8-byte chunk is stored starting at the address held in `r2`. The first four bytes come from `r0`, the second four bytes from `r1`.

Roughly equivalent C would be:

```
int32 *ptr=(int32 *) r2;
*(ptr) = r0;
*(ptr+1) = r1; // 'ptr+1' adds four bytes to the memory position
```